# supported NFC tags on Nexus 7

Tags: android, nfc, nexus-7

I tried to find what NFC chips does the Google Nexus 7 support and what kinda actions can be performed but somehow I find no suitable information.
I want to send an Intent via the NCF chip and start playing an audio for example, I got the Nexus 7 as a test device. Is that possible? What chips should be used?
I have a programmable Experia SmartTag and I found some info how to program it, but it will only work on experia devices I think..

Comment: Duplicated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119933/what-nfc-tags-does-the-nexus-7-support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look at Android Beam specification, these are the valid "tech"s that can be detected with an Android device:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/package-summary.html

I've made an example app like yours, using Mifare Ultralights, and it've worked.