# NDEF compatible NFC Chips

Tags: android, nfc

I'm looking for NFC chips that are NDEF compatible and supported by majority of devices running Android 4.x, somehow I could find only few info about that. Can someone name a manufacturer/chip model or provide some useful links?

Comment: generally I can say default Mifare Classic and Mifare Ultralight tags has Ndef feature.

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12129387/1202968 for an overview. Reading and writing MIFARE Classic chips is not supported on Nexus 4 and Nexus 10.